Lean 4 program to insert element in binary tree shows error: failed to sythesize instance `LT α`
I wrote a Lean 4 routine to insert a element into a binary tree and got the following error message: "failed to synthesize instance LT \alpha". Here is my program:
--binary trees
inductive BinTree (α: Type) where
  | leaf: BinTree α
  | branch: BinTree α -> α -> BinTree α -> BinTree α
deriving Repr

def BinTree.insert [LT α] (α: Type) (t: BinTree α) (x: α): BinTree α :=
  match t with
  | BinTree.leaf =>
      BinTree.branch BinTree.leaf x BinTree.leaf
  | BinTree.branch l y r =>
      if LT.lt x y then
        BinTree.branch
          (BinTree.insert α l x)
          y r
      else if LT.lt y x then
        BinTree.branch l y
          (BinTree.insert α r x)
      else
        BinTree.branch l y r

The error has its origin in the compare operations LT.lt x y and LT.lt y x in the function BinTree.insert. Does anybody know, what the reason for this error is and how I can fix the program? Thank you very much.

Here is some working code (but see notes at the bottom about why it may have issues with linear order assumptions):
set_option autoImplicit false

--binary trees
inductive BinTree (α : Type _) where
  | leaf: BinTree α
  | branch: BinTree α -> α -> BinTree α -> BinTree α
deriving Repr, Inhabited

def BinTree.insert {α : Type _} [LT α] [DecidableRel (fun (x y : α) => x < y)] (t : BinTree α) (x : α): BinTree α :=
  match t with
  | BinTree.leaf =>
      BinTree.branch BinTree.leaf x BinTree.leaf
  | BinTree.branch l y r =>
      if x < y then
        BinTree.branch
          (BinTree.insert l x)
          y r
      else if y < x then
        BinTree.branch l y
          (BinTree.insert r x)
      else
        BinTree.branch l y r

-- test that it works on common types
#eval BinTree.insert (BinTree.leaf) true -- Bool
#eval BinTree.insert (BinTree.leaf) 0    -- Nat
#eval BinTree.insert (BinTree.leaf) "a"  -- String
#eval BinTree.insert (BinTree.leaf) (-1) -- Int
#eval BinTree.insert (BinTree.leaf) [0]  -- List[Nat]

First, I added set_option autoImplicit false at the top to turn off auto implicit arguments.  This is not strictly needed, but it prevents errors like you were seeing.  When you write [LT α] without a preceding (α : Type) then Lean automatically adds {α : Type _} in front, which would have been fine if you didn't later add (α : Type) after.  (Types declarations should go in front of type classes for that type.)  By additionally adding the (α : Type) there were two α types being defined and Lean did weird things.  I would just turn off auto-implicits in all your projects for now to avoid confusing error messages like this.
Next, with (α: Type) [LT α] in the correct order, we see a new problem:
failed to synthesize instance
  Decidable (x < y)

This is because x < y (or equivalently LT.lt x y) is Prop-valued, not Bool-valued.  But if b then ... else ... requires b to be a Bool.  This is quite common, so Lean automatically converts most decidable operations, like < on the integers, from Prop to Bool by instantiating the type class DecidableRel.  To specify this for α we add an additional type class assumption [DecidableRel (fun (x y : α) => x < y)].  (You could also write it a bit more succinctly as [DecidableRel ((. : α) < .)].
Now it works for most common linearly ordered types, and I even provided some examples at the end.
I also cleaned up a few parts of the code.  I think it makes more sense to use {α : Type} instead of (α : Type) since Lean should be able in most circumstances to infer α from context.  I changed Type to Type _ to be a bit more general (although it probably doesn't matter for your use case).  I changed LT.lt x y to x < y which is equivalent and more idiomatic.

As an aside, while we need the < relationship to be decidable if we want to compute with BinTree.insert, what if we want to use BinTree.insert to just define an arbitrary mathematical tree with no reference to executable code?
This is exactly the sort of thing that Mathlib does.  In Mathlib, one commonly uses the axiom of choice to make a relationship decidable, even if it isn't computable.  By using choice, we break computability, but the definition still types checks.  Assuming import Mathlib at the top, we can also do the following:
import Mathlib
...
#check BinTree.insert (BinTree.leaf) (Real.pi)  -- real numbers
#check BinTree.insert (BinTree.leaf) (Cardinal.continuum)  -- cardinal numbers


The problem: Your code assumes a linear order
Now, the only problem I see with the above code is that you assume < is a total linear order.  But that isn't the contract for LT.  While I can't think of an example in base lean where < isn't total, in Mathlib, FinSet has a computable partial order < registered with LT.  Consider the following code:
#eval BinTree.insert (BinTree.insert (BinTree.leaf) ({0} : Finset Nat)) ({1} : Finset Nat)

With import Mathlib it would run, but it would have unexpected behavior creating a tree with only {0} in it instead of both {0} and {1} since the two sets are incomparable.
I see a few ways around this:

Just leave it be and provide a comment in your code.
For the final else branch, check if x = y and if not, then throw an error with panic.  For this, you need [DecidableEq α] for the equality check.  Also, you need that BinTree is inhabited for the panic (as panic is mathematically no more than returning the default element), but this is easy.  Just add deriving Inhabited (as I've already done).  Also, panic doesn't actually panic in #eval.  It only works correctly with compiled code (run in a Main function).
Mathlib provides a LinearOrder class for this sort of thing (which also handles the assumptions that the relations are decidable).
Lean's RBMap, for example, provides a different approach.  It explicitly includes the ordering in the type itself as a function cmp : α → α → Ordering.  You could add a similar assumption to BinTree.  Then your BinTree.insert would match on the result of cmp x y.  The type class Ord provides such a comparison for the most common data types, and the contract is that this should be a linear ordering.

I would personally go with the last approach.  This also has the advantage that the Tree itself controls what order objects are inserted into the tree.  Let's say you want for some reason to sort strings, not lexicographically, but first by length and then lexicographically within the same length.  You could do this by overriding LT locally, but you could accidentally override it in one file and not another.  So depending on what file you call BinTree.insert you could get different insert behavior.
